# I want to Use a drop-down and also text input

Tags: android, text, drop-down-menu, android-webview

I'm using android web view.In [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXnS0.png)

I want to Use a drop-down and also text input

Please help out I am struggling for 2 months

Comment: please check the image

Comment: you are using webview whole website  or native code?

Comment: thanks for your reply.im using web view whole website only

Comment: Is it working perfectly in browser? Only webview got problem.?

Comment: Yeah exactly ur correct is there any solution kindly help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know much, but my friend got same problem and it is website bug. For Android you can try to set User-agent like firefox or chrome.  post your webview code.